# How can I "bump" posts by ones with the latest comments AND have new posts with no comments appear at the top in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

For example: I want a post just submitted to appear at the top of the page. Then if someone comments on an older post, I'd now like this at the top.

This is my attempt but new posts don't appear and posts with multiple comments appear multiple times:

```
@posts = Post.joins(:comments).order("comments.created_at desc")
```

Comment: Did you try your query?, what's the problem?

Comment: Actually I'm mistaken...New Posts aren't appearing at all and Posts with comments are appearing multiple times depending how many comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to using `touch:`. Every new comment will update the updated_at of the post. Just follow this code for Comment model:

```
belongs_to :post, touch: true
```

More info: [apidock/touch](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch).

Comment: Thanks. Ideally it'd be great if adding then deleting a comment didn't leave the post at the top, but this works otherwise.

Comment: @mhkna In this case you should put `touch` to comments#create method, like: `if post.comment.save? post.touch`

Comment: Maybe I'm adding that wrong to my Comments controller, but that seems to still keep the deleted comment post on top.

Comment: @mhkna can you show controller code? P.s. If you put `touch` to controller, don't forget to remove him from model.

Comment: `def create  /n
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])  /n
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params) /n
    if @comment.save /n
      @post.touch /n
    end /n

    redirect_to post_path(@post) /n
  end` I'm not sure how to format that for comment

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of many aspects. `touch` does what you want, as proposed in [Michael 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48697524/2399861).

To achieve "rollback" you need a couple of things.

i. Add a column to comments, where you will store the current `updated_at` value of the **post**:

```
$ rails g migration add_post_date_to_comments post_date:datetime
$ rake db:migrate
```

ii. Add a callback in comment creation. Use after create to get the "touched" timestamp.

```
after_create { update(post_date: post.updated_at) }
```

iii. Add a callback for comment destroy, to rollback the update date of the post

```
 around_destroy { 
      if post.updated_at == created_at
          post.update_column(:updated_at, post_date)
       end # only rollback if this is the latest comment
 }
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      @post.touch
    end

    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
```

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so.